# Is there a tool that can tell a domain's IMAP or POP3 address?

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm building a web email client and I'm interested in easy ways to figure out imap or pop3 emails.  Is there a tool to help figure this out?

I'm assuming if not, my best bet would be

```
try { imap.domain.com } 
catch{ 
        try { mail.domain.com } 
        catch { ...etc ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way. Your best bet is to try the domain of the e-mail, plus the usual prefixes, as you suggest. Even then, an IMAP server may be running in a non-standard port; then you have no way of knowing.

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming this method will help me with >90-95% of all instances.  In the other cases, I can just ask users to find this information.  Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a DNS look up with a command line exec or something to look up their MX records and then parse it for the appropriate server.  Not sure how well it would work though.

On a linux OS, you can use `dig` or `host`, on Windows you can use `nslookup`.

Example use of each tool:

```
dig www.domain.com mx
host -t mx www.domain.com
nslookup -type=MX www.domain.com
```

Comment: That would only list the MX (mail exchanger) hosts, which are the SMTP servers. POP/IMAP has nothing to do with this and could be hiding behind any hostname.

Comment: You're right I suppose, can't take advantage of zone transfers much anymore either.